How to set the type on a catch phrase using a Language server plugin
Basically I am writing a ts plugin which will type the error in a try catch.
try {} catch(err: types here ){}.
Does someone know how Inside of the ts language server (I am writing a plugin) I can set the type?
I've tried to set the node.type to a copy of itself but change the node.kind to that of a string, but that failed. Ive checked around and i could not find a method which allows me to set it. (node.type is also declared readonly, so there's that, it seems to be able to only break things and not actually modify anything (if you set it to something wrong it breaks, but it does not seem to consume the .kind of on the node.type).
